# c# xml linq correct way?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i read about Linq and xml, but i dont know if i do it the right way...

here my XML Configuration File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Priorities>
    <Priority Index="0">Zero</Priority>
    <Priority Index="1">One</Priority>
    <Priority Index="2">Two</Priority>
    <Settings>
      <Name>PriorityName</Name>
      <DisplayName>PriorityDisplayName</DisplayName>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <Index>0</Index>
    </Settings>
  </Priorities>
  <Workcenters>
    <Workcenter Index="0">TEAM_0</Workcenter>
    <Workcenter Index="1">TEAM_1</Workcenter>
    <Workcenter Index="2">TEAM_2</Workcenter>
    <Settings>
    <Name>WorkcentersName</Name>
    <DisplayName>WorkcentersDisplayName</DisplayName>
    <Active>false</Active>
    <Index>1</Index>
    </Settings>
  </Workcenters>
  <ErrorPages>
    <ErrorPage>
      <Name>Error_1</Name>
      <Type>Critical</Type>
    </ErrorPage>
    <ErrorPage>
      <Name>Error_2</Name>
      <Type>Normal</Type>
    </ErrorPage>
 </ErrorPages>
</Configuration>
```

Now i access all **Priorities** like this:

```
 //Get Prios
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlPath2);
            IEnumerable<XElement> priorities = xelement.Descendants("Priorities");
            var prios = priorities.Elements("Priority").ToList();
            var settings = priorities.Elements("Settings");
            foreach (XElement priority in prios)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(priority.Attribute("Index").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(priority.Value);
            }

            foreach (XElement setting in settings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Name").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Active").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Index").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("DisplayName").Value);
            }
```

is this the right way to access the Elements?
i think there will be a better to read solution.

Can u help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XPathSelectElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelements?view=netcore-3.1) extension method.

So your code would look something like:

```
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlPath2);         

        foreach (XElement priority in xelement.XPathSelectElements("Priorities/Priority"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(priority.Attribute("Index").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(priority.Value);
        }

        foreach (XElement setting in xelement.XPathSelectElements("Priorities/Settings"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Name").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Active").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("Index").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(setting.Element("DisplayName").Value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you ! That is an easy way!